# Book about this boy that knows everything, including exactly when the world is going to end

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

It starts when he’s in the womb, all the way up until the world ends. There’s a part where he is a baby and he gets hypnotized by the TV. At some point in the story, I remember him growing up and being a famous baseball player.

Comment: Welcome to the site. When did you read this book, and roughly when do you think it was published?

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

This might be *[Everything Matters!](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6184241-everything-matters)* by Ron Currie Jr.

> In  infancy, Junior Thibodeaux is encoded with a prophecy: a comet will obliterate life on Earth in thirty-six years. Alone in this knowledge, he comes of age in rural Maine grappling with the question: Does anything I do matter? While the voice that has accompanied him since conception appraises his choices, Junior's loved ones emerge with parallel stories-his anxious mother; his brother, a cocaine addict turned pro-baseball phenomenon; his exalted father, whose own mortality summons Junior's best and worst instincts; and Amy, the love of Junior's life and a North Star to his journey through romance and heartbreak, drug-addled despair, and superheroic feats that could save humanity. While our recognizable world is transformed into a bizarre nation at endgame, where government agents conspire in subterranean bunkers, preparing citizens for emigration from a doomed planet, Junior's final triumph confounds all expectation, building to an astonishing and deeply moving resolution. Ron Currie, Jr., gets to the heart of character, and the voices who narrate this uniquely American tour de force leave an indelible, exhilarating impression.

Found with a search for `novel baby genius "world will end" baseball`